# How do you beat Ganon?

Tags: zelda-ocarina-of-time-3d

I have beat Ganondorf. When I begin the fight with Ganon, however, I have an issue. I do the part where you shoot his tail and then get my sword back, but after I get the sword, he moves too fast for me to hit him. No websites have been good thus far, most saying I am a noob and that I just need to get good at it.

Answer (score 2):

If you still have Magic power left you can stun hin with your light arrows.

If you don't have Magic power you can try to aim at his tail with the Hookshot.

A risky alternative is to try to get through his legs to hit his tail.

You can also use regular arrows. Hitting him right in the face will cause him to pause for a very brief moment, but this might buy you enough time to get to his tail.

It also helps to have the Biggoron sword for its extended range. Especially during the time when you have to fight without the Master sword.

Regarding your specific problem with the 3DS: Yes, stepping around him is a bit more difficult with the 3DS than it was with the N64 controller's analog stick. It's possible though.

Comment: Regarding going through his legs... the easiest way is _probably_ to roll through, but I haven't played the game since the N64 version, and don't have my copy anymore, so I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: Id like to point out that the building pieces that surround him can be destroyed by him and usually yield arrows or magic jars.

Answer (score -1):

standing between his legs and blowing yourself up will quickly stun him